# Rails Geocoder object does not contain postcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

Using rails Geocoder gem.Trying to search with postcode but it's returning nil while the postcode is valid.
Geocoder.search(454774) => nil

sample postcode : 454774

Note : nil value is coming because the postcode is missing in search object.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it likes that you're giving it an integer. Looking at the [github](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#basic-search) I am expecting that they want you to give them a string instead. I'm not personally familiar with a zip code of this length. As long as it's a valid zip code I would expect it to return something. Does this work?

```
Geocoder.search("454774")
```

Comment: String argument is also giving the [ ] result and it's a valid zipcode of Dhar , MP (India)